# Login info using symfony and user provider

Tags: symfony4

I'd like to understand how the security work with user providers. In security.yaml I can write :

```
   providers:
       entity_provider:
           entity:
               class: App\Entity\User
               property: userLogin
...
   firewalls:
...
           json_login:
               username_path: userLogin
```

And thus define "userLogin" as the proper field to use as "user name" for authentication. Is that correct? Then, why does it seems like my User class has to implement `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface::getUsername()` ? What's supposed to happen if those functions return something different from the conf? In which cases one will be used and not the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe method`Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface::getUsername()` is used across symfony to check wich property is used as an identifier, it's used in the authenticator, the firewall... It will be used by all the authentication methods. In your case, you should write

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getUsername(): ?string
{
    return $this->userLogin;
}
```

The property in the conf file will be looked at when you submit your login form in a regular web page. It's redundant.

Comment: Ok so they are indeed redundant... It's like symfony wants bugs to multiply.. My problem is that I have a userName field in User, with a doctrine generated getter getUserName, and php is not case sensitive so I would need to update my schema and fix all the necessary code.

Comment: @Shautieh, it's not like symphony want bugs to multiply, they mostly want retro-compatibility. That's how it worked before. For you userName field, yes, that's a collision, you can't do that.